# Excel data structures

Tags: microsoft-excel

For a data structure in a CSV:

job title, job location, bid date, bid 1, bid 2, bid 3.

Is there any way with excel to put all the bid data points for a given job title into the same cell? It doesn't need to be automated, just held in a single column of the spreadsheet.

Optimally, a user would be able to use a list of check boxes to select companies bidding on the job to include in that cell rather than picking one by one, in data validation drop downs across multiple cells.

The only solution I have currently is to put bids at the end of the sheet so that it can extend indefinitely but that only allows for one type of data of uncertain number.

Thanks!

Comment: You want multiple entries of data in a *single cell*?

Comment: I don't need to do anything with the data, I just need to use it as a note in a single cell, the string in the cell would look like: "Bid 1, Bid 2, Bid 3" rather than each of those being in their own cell. That makes the data a definite size

Comment: I might build a user form with check boxes for each of the possible bidders that then writes the value of each box checked to a single cell separated by commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume Bid 1, 2 and 3 are in Columns D, E and F, and data starts in Row 2.
In `G2` put

`=D2&", "&E2&", "&F2`

and fill down as necessary.

You can then copy Column G, and `Paste Special... > Values` back into Column G, and then delete Columns D, E and F if necessary.

Comment: Thanks yeah, what I'm doing for now is using a separate sheet with column A = job name, and then B through Z with bid entries. I'm doing a summary cell on the original sheet with basically your formula and an If(isblank) added in to grab all of the entries. Hopefully that's the best of both worlds.

Comment: Glad you got it working.